# Block access to an application from Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I want to block acces to an application on tomcat after a specific date.

There is something to do on the tomcat configuration?

Thank's.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in Tomcat that would do this out of the box, but it's quite trivial to write a simple [Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Valve.html) which does that.

Just take [RequestFilterValve.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RequestFilterValve.java.html) as an example and simplify its `process` method so it always sends `HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN` if the current date is later than some configured date.